# How to calculate row / col from grid position?

Tags: math, language-agnostic

Given a grid where I know the number of rows (which is fixed), and I know the current count of columns (which can grow arbitrarily), how do I calculate the row and column of an square from it's index?

```
           +   +   +   +   +
 Cols ---> | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | ...
        +--+---|---|---|---|---
         0 | 0 | 3 | 6 | 9 | ...
        +--+---|---|---|---|---
 Rows    1 | 1 | 4 | 7 | A | ...
        +--+---|---|---|---|---
         2 | 2 | 5 | 8 | B | ...
        +--+---|---|---|---|---
         .   .   .   .   .   ...
         .   .   .   .   .   .
         .   .   .   .   .   .
```

So, given:

```
final int mRowCount = /* something */;
int mColCount;
```

And given some function:

```
private void func(int index) {

    int row = index % mRowCount;
    int col = ???
```

How do I correctly calculate `col`?  It must be a function of both the number of columns and rows, I'm pretty sure.  But my brain is failing me.

Sample:  If `index == 4`, then `row = 1`, `col = 1`.  If `index == 2` then `row = 2`, `col = 0`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`int col = index / mRowCount;`

Answer (score 8):

Didn't really understand your setup but if you got a normal grid with a progressive index like in the Android `GridLayout`:

```
 +-------------------+
 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
 |---|---|---|---|---|
 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 
 |---|---|---|---|---|
 | 10| 11| 12| 13| 14|
 |---|---|---|---|---|
 | 15| 16| 17| 18| 19| 
 +-------------------+
```

The calculation is:

```
int col = index % colCount;
int row = index / colCount;
```

For example:

```
row of index 6 = 6 / 5 = 1
column of index 12 = 12 % 5 = 2
```

Comment: Ok, now, what if I wanted paging? I wanted a max of, say 3 rows per page. Thus for the above, rows `1, 2, 3` would be on page 1 and row `4` would be on page 2. I want the `int row = ....` formula to return `1` for `15..19`.

Answer (score 6):

`index = col * mRowCount + row`

then

`row = index % mRowCount;`

`col = index / mRowCount;`

Answer (score 4):

I believe the column would be obtained by integer division:

```
int col = index / mRowCount;
```

It would be possible to limit it to a single division (eliminate the modulus operation) by replacing it with a multiplication and subtraction.  I'm not sure if that is less costly; probably wouldn't matter in most situations:

```
int col = index / mRowCount;
int row = index - col * mRowCount;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
row = CEILING(index / numberOfColumns)
```

CEILING rounds up to the next integer

```
col = MOD(index / numberOfColumns)
```

and this with one exception which you must take into account -->  when MOD=0, when col result is ZERO, then you set  your  `col=numberOfColumns`
(so for example, let say `numberOfColumns=48`... then,  `MOD(96, 48)` is ZERO, and so is  `MOD(48, 48)=0`  ... cause anything divisible by 48 will be MOD=0...  in other words, when MOD=0 you are in the LAST or HIGHEST column, you are in numberOfColumns column

Answer (score 0):

```
column = index / max_rows;
row    = index % max_rows;
```

Answer (score 0):

row = index / numberOfColumns

and

column = index % numberOfColumns